# is there any function that help in adding friends in flutter app and sort them?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a chat app using flutter and firebase as backend, and I want these functionalities,

1. I need to implement an add friend function and add it to the contacts list.
2. Whenever a user talks to a contact its chatroom gets sorted in the list to the top like messenger.

how can I do it, should I use firestore or database ?
Link to the GitHub repo of this project: https://github.com/Maxcousin123/whatzapp.git

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question seems like no prior research has gone into it. Before you get into the nitty-gritty of having a working contact/friend list, why don't you work on the actual chatting protocol beforehand?

Comment: This seems like more of a "can you do the work for me?" question. Start out doing your own research, and if that doesn't help and you cannot find a way, we'll be glad to help

Comment: I am researching this function for 2 weeks, and tried everything before posting here to not see the usual rude answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Firestore for chat application might not be the best approach, since it requires a lot of reads and writes and Firestore rates depend more on reads and writes than storage.

For real-time updates, use `FireStore` as it provides a stream of data that is very helpful when using `StreamBuilder`.

> Create Firestore collection for `chats`

> In this collection, main a unique document for each user, with userId as documentId

> Create a subcollection, named `chatRooms`, and for each `chatRooms` document create a field `lastMessageTime`, that will be used for sorting.

Your firestore structure should look like this,

- chat (collection)
  |

  - userId
    |

    - chatRooms (Subcollection)
      |

      - chatRoomId
        |

        - lastMessageTime (TimeStamp - Field)
        - lastMessageData (String - Field)
        - messages (Subcollection)

To get the chatRoom with latest activity on top, sort data from `chatRooms` collection according to `TimeStamp`.

```
Firestore.instance
.collection("chat").doc(user.id).collection("chatRooms")
     .orderBy('lastMessageTime', descending: true).getDocuments()
```

P.S: This might not be the best solution, but you can learn by trying.

Comment: Firestore isn't the best solution for a chat app since you have a lot of reads and writes, for this use case realtime databse is better @ASAD HAMEED

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.
@AnanSaadi can you please edit the answer accordingly. I haven't worked with `Realtime Database` lately.